# AngularJS - how to pass a value of variable as a key in query params using $resource?

Tags: angularjs, rest, get, query-string

I am struggling to pass the value of a variable as a key to the query params for a GET using $resource in a Angularjs application:

Below is the code:

//Controller

```
..
.
var value = obj.value; // Y 
var category = obj.category; //ctrlpart
//category contains a dynamic value which needs to go as a key
..
.

scope.materialDataPromise = MaterialData.query(
            {
                "query" : keyword,
                "ftype" : ftype,
                category : value,
                "start" : 0,
                "rows" : 1000
            }, function(response) {
```

So that the request can look like

```
http://test.com:8080/JunkAPI/MaterialServlet?query=0091&start=0&rows=1000&crtclpart=Y
```

> &crtclpart=Y

OR with multiple dynamic values

```
http://test.com:8080/JunkAPI/MaterialServlet?query=0091&start=0&rows=1000&crtclpart=Y&invoice=ALL
```

> &crtclpart=Y&invoice=ALL

Below is the Service call:

```
apiService.factory("MaterialData", function ($resource) {
    var _url = "http://test.com:8080/JunkAPI/MaterialServlet;

    return $resource(_url, {}, {

        "query": {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Please suggest some options to handle this for multiple dynamic values to be passed as keys in the $resource rest api call

Answer (score 0):

```
var propName = 'crtclpart';
var value = 'Y';

var obj = {};
obj[propName ] = value;
scope.materialDataPromise = MaterialData.query(obj);
```